# jQuery displaying NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery, nan

I'm trying to get some data from a certain element in my HTML, but jQuery "NaN" when I ask jQuery to place the grabbed data in to a paragraph tag.

Here is my full code:

```
$(".next-panel").click(function(event) {

    var accordion = $(".nav-accordion")
    var index = accordion.accordion('option','active')
    var next = index + 1;
    var panel = $(this).parents('.accordion-panel').next();
    var sectionTitle = $(this).parents('.accordion-panel').parents('li').next('li').children('a').attr('data-title');
    var sectionDesc = $(this).parents('.accordion-panel').parents('li').next('li').children('a').attr('data-desc');
    var sectionPercent = $(this).parents('.accordion-panel').parents('li').next('li').children('a').attr('data-percent');

    $('body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#accordion-wrap').offset().top
    },
    800 
    );

    accordion.accordion('activate', next);
    panel.removeClass("ui-state-disabled").bind("click");


    $('#progress-box h6').text(sectionTitle);
    $('#progress-box p').text(sectionDesc);
    $('#percent-bar-inner p').text(sectionPercent);
    $('#percent-bar-inner').animate({
        width: sectionPercent,
    }, 300);

    console.log(sectionPercent)

    event.preventDefault();
    return false;


});
```

When I use this:

```
var sectionPercent = $(this).parents('.accordion-panel').parents('li').next('li').children('a').attr('data-percent');
```

and then tell it to output the Var to:

```
$('#percent-bar-inner p').text(sectionPercent);
```

It gives me:

```
NaN
```

But when I log the variable, it gives me:

```
50
```

Which is the correct value.

Why would this happen and what does NaN mean?!

---

### UPDATE

JS Fiddle examples:

This is a JS fiddle showing it working as expected:

http://jsfiddle.net/87QtE/

With these bits of my code removed:

```
var accordion = $(".nav-accordion")
var index = accordion.accordion('option','active')
var next = index + 1;
var panel = $(this).parents('.accordion-panel').next();
```

and also

```
accordion.accordion('activate', next);
panel.removeClass("ui-state-disabled").bind("click");
```

Comment: NaN means *Not a Number*.  Not sure why you're getting it though.

Comment: Please create a JSFIDDLE with the HTML & JS.

Comment: `NaN` is "Not a Number". It's an internal 'constant' in Javascript used for the results of illegal math operations, e.g. division by zero can produce a NaN.

Comment: And the width animates to 50, as expected ?

Comment: @Johnツ JSFiddle links updated in main question